# I Have an access Database and i have write following query for Get each employee salary by present day but i get error by using this query

Tags: sql, ms-access

When I run the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT  
    FORMAT(emp_attendance.att_date, 'mm-yyyy') AS pd ,
    emp_detail.ename ,
    emp_detail.ecode ,
    ( SELECT    COUNT(emp_attendance.att_id)
        FROM      emp_attendance
        WHERE     emp_attendance.eid = emp_detail.eid
                AND emp_attendance.att_type = 'Full Day'
                AND FORMAT(emp_attendance.att_date, 'mm-yyyy') = FORMAT(emp_attendance.att_date,
                                                            'mm-yyyy')
    ) AS Present_Days ,
    ( SELECT    COUNT(emp_attendance.att_id)
        FROM      emp_attendance
        WHERE     emp_attendance.eid = emp_detail.eid
                AND emp_attendance.att_type = 'Half Day'
                AND FORMAT(emp_attendance.att_date, 'mm-yyyy') = FORMAT(emp_attendance.att_date,
                                                            'mm-yyyy')
    ) AS Half_Days ,
    ROUND(( emp_detail.esalary / 30 )
            * ( ( SELECT  COUNT(emp_attendance.att_id)
                FROM    emp_attendance
                WHERE   emp_attendance.eid = emp_detail.eid
                        AND emp_attendance.att_type = 'Full Day'
                        AND FORMAT(emp_attendance.att_date, 'mm-yyyy') = FORMAT(emp_attendance.att_date,
                                                            'mm-yyyy')
                )
                + ( ( SELECT  COUNT(emp_attendance.att_id)
                    FROM    emp_attendance
                    WHERE   emp_attendance.eid = emp_detail.eid
                            AND emp_attendance.att_type = 'Half Day'
                            AND FORMAT(emp_attendance.att_date, 'mm-yyyy') = FORMAT(emp_attendance.att_date,
                                                            'mm-yyyy')
                    ) / 2 ) ), 2) AS Eligable_Salary
FROM    
    emp_attendance
    INNER JOIN emp_detail ON emp_attendance.eid = emp_detail.eid
GROUP BY 
    FORMAT(emp_attendance.att_date, 'mm-yyyy') ,
    emp_detail.eid ,
    emp_detail.ename ,
    emp_detail.ecode ,
    Eligable_Salary
HAVING  
    FORMAT(emp_attendance.att_date, 'mm-yyyy') = '11-2016'
```

... I receive the following error:

> You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified
>   expression 'ROUND(emp_detail.esalary/30*(+/2),2)' as part of an
>   aggregate function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help (Mark code and click `{}`, mark error messages and click `"`. Add line-breaks where needed.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Eligable_Salary in the GROUP BY clause you should use emp_detail.esalary